# Difference between self.response.write and self.response.out.write in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

What is the difference between `self.response.write` and `self.response.out.write` in google app engine?

Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

there is no difference.
webapp uses `self.response.out.write` and webapp2 `self.response.write` kept the `out` for compatibility reasons.
here the implentation of the `Response` Class:
http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/browse/webapp2.py#365